# How to find relations between two lists?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I have a list of a class that has two properties. int Id and list keys
I need to find the relations between the keys represented by the Ids. 
The list of keys can vary from 1-5 with maximum length of 5 while the Ids can vary from 1-7. 
I need to implement a way to find the highest ratio between key and value. 
If the Id 5 is always linked to a list of keys that contain 3 the output would be [3,5], even though there could be more Ids with 1 represented with key 4, because they have a lower ratio than 3 with 5 they would not be represented. 
For an example it could look something like this

```
Id       Keys

1       [1, 3, 4]
1       [1, 2, 3]
1       [1, 5]
3       [2, 5]
2       [1, 2, 3, 4]
3       [2, 5]
3       [5, 1]
1       [3, 6]
1       [6, 1]
```

Here both [3,5] has a 100% ratio and also 2 with 1,2,3 and 4.
The output should then still be 3 with 5 because they are more often represented while ratio still is 100%.

Edit: Just need the highest sum for each key by Id,  Ex: Id 1,  key 1, sum 4

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs defined **in code** and clearly defined expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Keys", typeof(List<int>));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, new List<int>() {1, 3, 4}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, new List<int>() {1, 5}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, new List<int>() {2, 5}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, new List<int>() {2, 5}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, new List<int>() {5, 1}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, new List<int>() {3, 6}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, new List<int>() {6, 1}}); 

            var temp = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .SelectMany(x => x.Field<List<int>>("Keys").Select(y => new {key = y, value = x.Field<int>("Id")}).ToList()).ToList();

            var counts = temp.GroupBy(x => x.key).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, count = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

Comment: Almost, it just need to sort by Id, say Id 1 has 3 of key 4.